# Custom Post type data

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to know the best way to acheive this .

I have a csv file 350 MB . It contains more than 200k records each record has 21 fields like name , address , number email etc . I want to upload that file so each record can easily be editable , searchable .

so what i did i use easy content post type plugin , i created 21 fields in that as a result that plugin store data in postmeta table which has 4 columns only (id , post_id ,meta_key ,meta_value) so data is something like this now

```
id     post_id     meta_key     meta_value
45        606       ecpt_name     Honda
46        606       ecpt_tel      123456
```

Now i want to do searching with limit of number of search . Secondly is there any other good way to do that whole process i really dont like to store 21 fields of data like that as later i have to join this data with another csv file data

Comment: So sorry to tell you, but is so hard to take a good snapshot of what you have, just reading words. I think you should drop here an example of your CSV, of your database, a dump of your `post_meta`s. I'm sorry ahead if I'm not understanding due to my ignorance. :)

Comment: i tried to rewrite it :)